# Retrofit 2.0.0 beta2 : expected begin_array but was begin_object

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

i'm receiving every time this Error : **expected begin_array but was begin_object** i don't know if i need to add a deserializer or a warrper class to retrofit but i don't know how i can do it in a easy way to fit my api json response for all my project , here is my retrofit code try  :

-

**My Json** :

```
{
  categoryDetails: [

    {
      id: "1",
      categoryName: "Fashion"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      categoryName: "Pets"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      categoryName: "Sports"
    },
    {
      id: "4",
      categoryName: "Autre1"
    },
    {
      id: "5",
      categoryName: "Autre2"
    }
  ]
}
```

My Source Code

```
import java.util.List;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import android.util.Log;
import retrofit.Call;
import retrofit.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit.Retrofit;
import retrofit.http.GET;
import retrofit.http.Path;

public class GitHubClient {

     public static final String API_URL = "http://192.168.1.22";


      public static class Category {
        public final String categoryName;
        public final int id;

        public Category(String categoryName, int id) {
          this.categoryName = categoryName;
          this.id = id;
        }
      }
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
      public interface QampaAPI {
        @GET("/api/category")
        Call<List<Category>> categoryDetailss();
      }
 /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/     

      public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {

           Log.w("retrofit","main()");
        // Create a very simple REST adapter which points the GitHub API.
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

        // Create an instance of our GitHub API interface.
        QampaAPI apiCall = retrofit.create(QampaAPI.class);

        // Create a call instance for looking up Retrofit categoryDetailss.
        Call<List<Category>> call = apiCall.categoryDetailss();

        // Fetch and print a list of the categoryDetailss to the library.
        List<Category> Categorys = call.execute().body();

        for (Category Category : Categorys) {
          Log.w("retrofit",Category.categoryName + " (" + Category.id + ")");
        }


      }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the error state that your JSON response does not match with class you created.
Try following POJO class

```
public static class Category { 
public final List<CatergoryItem> categoryItem;

    public Category(List<CategoryItem> item) {
      this.categoryItem = item;
    }

  }
class CategoryItem{
 public String categoryName;
    public int id;
 //getter..setter 
}
```

Comment: i still have the same error here is my code : collabedit.com/qbn3p

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you need a wrapper class to handle the outer object --

```
static class CategoryDetails {
     List<Category> categoryDetails;
     // add getter and setter
}
```

Update your interface to use this object --

```
public interface QampaAPI {
    @GET("/api/category")
    Call<CategoryDetails> categoryDetailss();
}
```

and your calls --

```
Call<CategoryDetails> call = apiCall.categoryDetailss();
CategoryDetails details = call.execute().body();
```

You will need to access the list from inside the `details` object to iterate over it.